# Access VBA: object invalid or no longer set

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get the following error:

```
object invalid or no longer set
```

when my code is running the following string:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
```

According to me, I get this error because there is no record selected or the record selected is `Nothing`.

How can I add a check before executing the code? It would be great to have something like:

```
If SelectedRecord != Nothing then
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this.

The easiest way is just to turn on control wizards, and choose records operations -> delete record. That generates an embedded macro. You can just use it, or use it as a reference for the required steps.

A fully VBA solution is the following one:

```
Dim rs As Recordset: Set rs = Me.Recordset
With rs
    If Not rs.Updatable Then
        'RS is not updateable, delete will fail
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then '0 records
        If Me.NewRecord Then
            If Not Me.Dirty Then
                'Do nothing, unchanged new record so won't be saved
            Else
                'Revert changes on new record
                Me.Undo
            End If
        Else
            .Delete
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Note that I'm purposefully not using `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord`. This is because I want to be able to specify on which form (e.g. subform) I'm deleting the record.

Comment: I think `If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then` could be changed to `If .Updatable And Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then` to avoid the extra `If` statement; also, `If Not Me.Dirty Then` changed to `If Me.Dirty Then` to omit the need for an `Else` statement.

Comment: @LeeMac That's certainly true. I included these steps because I often use descriptive error messages when the delete fails. This code, however, has none of those.

Comment: No problem Erik; I struggle to find fault with your code. :-)